# Security updates to 3.3.2

Tags: php, security, upgrade

I know all security updates are important but given that how important on a scale from 1 to 10 is it to upgrade from 3.1.3 to 3.3.2.

I have some sites that need to be upgraded but the host has me locked down in an older version of php that limits me to 3.1.3.

I am currently running version 5.2.3 of php.

Thanks,
Bart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WP 3.1.3 has come out, we've released:

- 3.1.4 - **security update**
- 3.2
- 3.2.1 - **security update**
- 3.3
- 3.3.1 - **security update**
- 3.3.2 - **security update**

On a scale of 1-10, skipping a single security update is about a 3 (bad, but not catastrophic).  Skipping *4* security updates, though, would be closer to an 8-9 ...

You should seriously consider moving to a new host if they're locking you on PHP 5.2.3.  Even PHP 5.2.4 included [several security updates](http://php.net/releases/5_2_4.php), and the 5.2.X branch maxed out at 5.2.14.  The current stable for PHP is 5.4 (thought 5.3.9 is still pretty solid).

Comment: Thank you, that helps. I will look at migrating the sites to a new host.